# Unique words in Multiple Files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I Have calculated unique words and their frequencies in a single file using unique function..

```
fid = fopen(filename);

words = textscan(fid, '%s');

status = fclose(fid);

unique_words = unique(words{1,1}); 

frequencies = zeros(numel(unique_words), 1);

for i = 1:numel(unique_words)
if max(unique_words{i} ~= ' ')
    for j = 1:numel(words{1,1})
        if strcmp(words{1,1}(j), unique_words{i})
            frequencies(i) = frequencies(i) + 1;                      
        end
    end
end
end
```

Can anyone please tell me that how can I do this for multiple files? I mean if I am having four files? And moreover, after I have list of unique words in single file, how can I check through Matlab code that which words appears how many times in each file?

Thanks

Comment: put your above code into a function file, and call this function from inside a for loop, iterating over your filenames. And about your edit: you should ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function [frequencies] = calc_unique_words(filename)
fid = fopen(filename);

words = textscan(fid, '%s');

status = fclose(fid);

unique_words = unique(words{1,1}); 

frequencies = zeros(numel(unique_words), 1);

for i = 1:numel(unique_words)
if max(unique_words{i} ~= ' ')
    for j = 1:numel(words{1,1})
        if strcmp(words{1,1}(j), unique_words{i})
            frequencies(i) = frequencies(i) + 1;                      
        end
    end
end
end
```

Then in another file, say "main.m" do this:
Make sure your file names are listed on the top line:

```
fileNames = {'f1.txt' , 'file2.bcd', 'filename3.txt','theLastFilename.csv'}
for ii = 1:numel(fileNames)
    freq_cell{ii} = calc_unique_words(fileNames{ii});
end
```

Comment: Hey NKN thanks foh help but the function: 

function [frequencies] = calc_unique_words(filename)

Is it for a single file?Cuz I wish to do this for multiples...

Thanks Again.........

Comment: the function is your own code, then you will use it multiple times.

Comment: and you mean that all four files or multiple files will be put in last freq_cell function you mentioned right?

Comment: first of all you copy-paste the first function to an .m file and save it as 'calc_unique_words.m' file. Then you make another file named 'main.m' an copy-paste the for ii=1:4 .... part. If you run the main.m file it calls the calc_unique_words function for each file in the list.

Comment: I did but error is still remaining... i.e. 

Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier

Comment: and the other one...

freq_cell{ii} = calc_unique_words(['Sports' num2str(ii) '.txt']);

Comment: you need to change the filename in the code according to your filenames and also you should make sure that the matlab files and the other files are in the same path.

Comment: I updated the post so it no longer requires filenames to be numbered from `1` to `n`. @MazharIqbalRana Perhaps this is more clear?

Comment: @NKN and Dennis

Thanks so much both of you... You Guys helped me a lot... Thanks so much I shall surely cite you both in my Thesis Work Thanks again :D

Comment: ok Temme one more thing @DennisJaheruddin after getting all unique words and their frequencies.. I will have list of unique words now ... How Can I now check in this final unique words file that which word appears how many times in each file? I tried doing it manually but it takes lots of times......

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana That is an entirely different question. I would recommend you to try it, and if it fails create a new question. Make sure to include (only) the relevant information for that subquestion and show your attempted solution.